# Start a task from an InfoPath form?

Tags: 2007, infopath, form

I have an InfoPath form which is used for meeting reports. In these reports we want to start a task for a person who has to do something. The idea is that when a table is filled in a task is automatically started for the person who has a new task assigned to him from the meeting report.

If my question isn't clear please say so.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: @Jack: Move the text from your answer to the `add comment` feature on Jaap's post and he will get notified of your question. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your question is this:

After a meeting has taken place, someone creates a new meeting report by filling in an InfoPath form. In this form you select a user. When you submit the form a task list item needs to be created automatically and assigned to the selected user.

Is this correct? If so, I would definately NOT use VSTA (code behind for InfoPath forms) as Novice suggests. Instead, I would either write a workflow (strongly recommended if you want something else to automatically happen when the user completes the task) or an EventReceiver. Another alternative would be to write a Timer Job that periodically processes your document library with InfoPath forms and creates the task list items.

I am not sure, but you might be able to get away with a SharePoint Designer workflow, which requires the least amount of coding.

Comment: A simple SharePoint designer workflow that takes action based on the status of a form field is probably the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Use VSTA in Infopath, and basically you can write code to access the Task List and create one using the sharepoint Object model.

Use some unique identifiers to establish mapping between the meeting reports ad tasks.

Note : if VSTA is used, you cannot publish it straight forward, as its has to go through approvals of the farm admin :)

Answer (score 0):

I need to do the similar workflow. I am still trying to find the solution for it. Can anyone provide more detail or post a url link so I can follow certain steps to achieve "Use VSTA in Infopath, and basically you can write code to access the Task List and create one using the sharepoint Object model.
Use some unique identifiers to establish mapping between the meeting reports ad tasks". Thanks.